# Chrome Extensions: CSS Injection on Manifest Version 3

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am attempting to inject CSS code into the active tab from a chrome extension, yet nothing I have looked at online so far has worked for me. I am fairly new to all of this, so apologies if my question is a bit naive and I am just missing something basic. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
function inject_1(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    css = 'body { background-color = "red" !important; }';
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS(
     {
       target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
       css: css,
     }, function() {
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting css : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
       }
     });
  });
}
```

Here is a secondary method I tried:

```
function inject_2(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
     {
       target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
       files: ["inject.css"],
     }, function() {
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting css : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
       }
     });
  });
}
```

Neither function returns an error message, but they also don't change the webpage at all. I would greatly appreciate any help with this (rework of my code or something completely new to try). Thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't add the URL to `host_permissions` in manifest.json.

Comment: My current permissions are:  `"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "https://www.google.com/"]` and I added new host permissions `"host_permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "https://www.google.com/"]` in response to your comment. It still doesn't work. Sidenote: what is the difference between permissions and host permissions?

Comment: You need to split permissions and host permissions, see [an example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#host-permissions).

Comment: Do you mean like this: `"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
"host_permissions": ["https://www.google.com/"]` to have the program work on google?

Comment: Yes, see the example I've linked and read the entire migration guide, too.

Comment: I am facing same issue but I am getting error "cannot access chrome:// URL"

Answer (score 15):

Bit late, but I got this working for a personal project; maybe try something to the effect of:

```
...
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
        target: { tabId: tabs.id },
        files: ["inject.css"]
    });
...
```

You can [specify files for insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-CSSInjection) as you've done for executeScript in your secondary method.

Comment: I think what makes things confusing is that `executeScript`'s [ScriptInjection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection) says that it accepts CSS files, which does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

I would just add a .css file to the extension.

style.css

```
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

and then added it to the `content_scripts` in manifest.json e.g.

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    ...,
    "css": ["style.css"]
  }
```

I'm also not sure if your `'body { background-color = "red" !important; }'` shouldn't be `'body { background-color:red !important; }'`

Comment: I do have that (being "css":["inject.css"]) included in my manifest already and the css edit suggested above (replace "=" with ":") is correct (was a typo, my bad) but didn't end up making a difference. The CSS injection still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is loading?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely loading in,